# I have a 3D numpy histogram and its edges. How do I write this to a .fits file with the edges encoded in the axis information?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, astropy, fits

I have a set of data that I have converted into a 3D numpy histogram, and have saved the corresponding edge data. I would like to be able to take the histogram along with the edges and save them as a data cube. I know how to save the histogram data themselves as a fits file, but I'm not entirely sure how to save the 3 arrays of edge values that I have so that they serve as a coordinate system when I open the file and plot the data. I know it might have to do with specifying some header keywords like CDELT or something, but I'm not clear on how it all works, so any help would be greatly appreciated! I included some sample code as well to show what I'm trying to do.

```
from astropy.io import fits
import numpy as np

histogram = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(50, 50, 50))
edges = [np.linspace(10, 20, 51), np.linspace(13, 45, 51), np.linspace(-30, 30, 51)]

hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(histogram)
hdu.writeto('histogram.fits')

# How do I now include "edges" into the fits file as axis information?
```

Comment: Perhaps [this code](https://cta-observatory.github.io/ctapipe/_modules/ctapipe/utils/fitshistogram.html) might offer some hints.  I think what it refers to as "ranges" are your "edges", the difference being that for each one it only takes the min and max value, and assumes the bins are evenly spaced (so no need to use `np.linspace` explicitly).  Indeed it fills the correct `CRDELT`, `CRVAL`, and other coordinate keywords in the header.

Comment: Thank you so much!